# Extracting data (array) from named spreadsheet using phpspreadsheet lib

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I can't understand, how i can extract  data (array) from named spreadsheet using [phpspreadsheet lib](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/), for ex, i have workbook with many named spreadsheet (fisrt,**second** etc), I get array, with all named spreadsheets:

**Code:**

```
$inputFileName = 'uploads/1.xlsx';
$inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$worksheetNames = $reader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($worksheetNames);
echo "</pre>";
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => firts
    [1] => second
    [2] => third
)
```

By using [this example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Reader/05_Simple_file_reader_using_the_read_data_only_option.php), I can get all data of active (first) spreadsheet:

```
$sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
print_r($sheetData);
```

but how I can get for specific one, "**second**" spreadsheet data?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Reader/07_Simple_file_reader_loading_a_single_named_worksheet.php

Comment: how i can extract data, from this spreadsheet, in this ex, i can only get sheetname, w/o data

Comment: Not sure but maybe `$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1');` can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$spreadsheet->getSheetNames();
```

for to get a list of all sheets or you can iterate

```
for($i=1;$i<4;$i++){

    $spreadsheet->getSheet($i);
}
```

For more information, check the link [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worksheets/).